# XAML ComboBox show all items at once

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app for my school project. I am running into a problem that when I create a ComboBox (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox), all 6 items display at once in 6 rows. I want a ComboBox that show the down arrow, when I select the arrow it should show a list of item that I can select. This drives me nut. I searched but didn't find the answer.

Here is my ComboBox in XAML.

```
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item4</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item5</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item6</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Is there a property I need to set for the ComboBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't have a ComboBox, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) recommends using a ListPicker. Download the 
[Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).